# Linear mixed effect models - Why is time specific variance under estimated?

Tags: r, glmm, lm

Suppose you fit a linear mixed effect model

$$y_{ij} = \mu + \beta^T x_{ij} + u_i + \epsilon_{ij}$$

where $u_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0,\nu^2)$.

I have noticed that when fitting this model in R using synthetic data (that is specifically generated to follow the above model) using the lme package:

```
  model <- lme(y~1+x1+x2,data=dat,~1|id/time)
  id = i, time=j
```

the package will yield extremely accurate estimates for $\sigma^2$, but $\nu^2$ will be systematically under estimated. Examples

$$\sigma = \nu = 1 \implies  \hat{\sigma}\approx 1, \hat{\nu} \approx 0.91$$

$$\sigma = \nu = 0.5 \implies  \hat{\sigma}\approx 0.5,  \hat{\nu} \approx 0.43$$

This problem does not seem to improve with sample size.

I'm curious if there's an intuitive reason for this, and if it can be corrected for?

Comment: what is id and time? "~1|id/time" should generate the Z matrix for random effect. Do you know what kind of Z will be?

Comment: $id$ is an identifying factor for each individual. $time$ is the time for observation $j$ of individual $i$. eg.$id =1,2,...n$ while $t=1,2,...,T$. My aim with that code is to include two random intercepts, one for $i$ and one for $i:T$, which I thought is what $id/time$ constructs for $Z$?

Comment: Did you do simulation? otherwise how can you know the values of parameters? From the model, you just have one random intercept. I guess change "~1|id/time" to "-1|id" or "~1|time" you will get correct $\hat v$.

Comment: Yes, I did the simulation. What do you mean "-1|id" or "~1|time"?  "-1|id" does not seem to work in lme (unless Im misunderstanding). I can get correct estimate for "time" if I exclude "id" from the model formula, but when "id" is included time is under estimated. Is there a way to correct without removing id?

Comment: should be "~1|id". typo. i = id, j = time?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was not clear.

Comment: Then should be :~1|id". Do not know how did you generated data? Are you sure that data are generated according to your specified model strictly?

Comment: ~1|id fits an intercept for each $i$ giving an estimate of $\sigma$, but not of $\nu$? For some reason lme does not allow me to include intercepts for $1|id$ and $1|id:time$ separately, so I am forced to use $1|id/time$. If I replace $time$ by a factor which is unique to all observations, say $ep$, then I get the same results by fitting $list(~1|id,~1|ep)$ as for $~1|id/t$.

Comment: I am fairly certain the generation is correct. The model is pretty simple, but I will double check.

Comment: For mixed model $Y=X\beta + Z\gamma +\epsilon$, try hard to understand matrix Z. Could you write down Z that you used to generate you data?

Comment: $Z$ is of the form (for $T=3):
$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1  & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0  & 1
\end{bmatrix}


with $ \gamma = [u_i, \epsilon_{i1}, \epsilon_{i2}, \epsilon_{i3}]^T $

Comment: page 4 on this https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/490/10/mixed-effects/mixed-effects-01.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mathematical formulation and the R code you present do not match. Namely, the mathematical formulation is for a simple random intercepts models, whereas the code for a model with nested random intercepts. That is, the model behind the code is: $$\left \{ \begin{eqnarray} \begin{array}{l} y_{ijk} = \mu + \beta^T x_{ijk} + u_i + b_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk},\\ u_i \sim \mathcal N (0, \sigma_u^2), \;\; b_{ij} \sim \mathcal N (0, \sigma_b^2), \;\; \epsilon_{ijk} \sim \mathcal N (0, \sigma^2). \end{array}\end{eqnarray}\right.$$

The code behind the model you’ve written in mathematical formulation should be something like:

```
model <- lme(y ~ time + x1 + x2, data = dat, random = ~ 1 | id)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. In the results from running your code I get:
 Formula: ~1 | i
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.002582 1.002047

Here, is 1.0025 the estimate of $\sigma_u^2$, while 1.002047 the estimate of $\sigma^2$? That would make a lot of sense.